# Does named pipe modify the filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, pipe, fifo

If I create a named pipe and then read/write on it, is the filesystem where the named pipe resides affected? I.e. is the data buffered on the filesystem until read, or does it reside in memory only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file object itself is created in the filesystem, but no data is stored in a file system.  From the mkpipe(3) manpage:

```
   A  FIFO special file is similar to a pipe, except that it is created in
   a different way.  Instead of being an anonymous communications channel,
   a  FIFO  special  file  is  entered  into  the  file  system by calling
   mkfifo().
```

About the only time the data might be stored on disk is during hibernation when memory is written to the swap space, including buffers - however this an corner case.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. The named pipe's presence on the file system seems to just be a way of generating a handy label/handle (a file path), rather than building out some orthogonal resource identification system.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. Writing to a named pipe does not modify the filesystem (except for access times).

Here's a demonstration:

```
$ mkdir test
$ mkdir test-ro
$ mkfifo test/fifo
$ mount --bind test test-ro
$ mount -o remount,ro test-ro
$ cat test/fifo & echo something >> test/fifo
something
```

As you can see, even though the fifo was on a read-only filesystem, we were able to write to it.

Named pipes don't store any piped data on the filesystem. Their data is buffered in memory, separate from the filesystem buffers.

Comment: Wouldn't a slow consumer of the fifo pipe cause the buffer to page to disk?